# Path on subprocess check_output

Tags: python, linux, cron, posix

When executing a python script with crontab, the script lacks environment variables.

The script calls an executable which some Linux distributions ship under `/usr/bin` and other under `/sbin`.

`subprocess.check_output()` doesn't account for this.

Can I assume that `which` is always under `/usr/bin/which`?
Is `Popen` the better alternative with `env=os.environment.copy()`?

I've tried with `shell=True` and `sh -c` in the crontab.

```py
#read the Kernel's routing table by calling /usr/bin/route -n
routes = str(subprocess.check_output(["route", "-n"]), "utf-8")
```

see https://github.com/pzillmann/wireguard-dynamic-routing/blob/master/wg-dynroute.py#L32

I expect the script to show equal behavior when called in a bash session and called in crontab.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'route'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When executing a python script with crontab, the script lacks environment variables.

It probably depends on which `cron` we're talking about. Vixie cron sets `PATH`, `HOME` and `SHELL` and `LOGNAME`.

Any but `LOGNAME` can be overridden in `/etc/crontab` or your own `crontab` file. So set up a proper `PATH` in your crontab file.

Comment: A `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` on top of the crontab solved the problem. Sometimes it is the easiest solution. Thanks.